# Is Foreign Income taxable In India

Tags: income-tax, india, non-resident, foreign-income, portugal

I was abroad from 2 years(so NRI currently), Now returned to India in April and working for Portuguese company individually and they need me to send invoices monthly for the payment.
Now this company need my VAT/fiscal number for taxation purpose. **What should I provide here?**

Also, **what will the good way for me to save tax in India**, Should I accept the amount individually or should I start a company and accept the amount on company's account?

The Portuguese company will be paying my tax in Portugal. **So do I also need to pay tax in India.**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**What should I provide here?**

This would be your PAN number.

**So do I also need to pay taxes in India?**

Yes, if you reside for > 182 days in India in a fiscal year, you're required to pay income tax on your foreign income.

**What will a good way for me to save tax in India?**

Depends on many factors -  amount, other additional income sources etc. Would be wiser to consult a tax expert on this rather than share confidential data here.

Comment: In other country’s laws, income that you have while in the country isn’t “foreign income”. On a beach in Spain working remotely for a company in Canada, your pay will count as “Spanish” income.

Comment: @gnasher729 How is your comment relevant to this question? This was specifically about India.